# How to increase net.core.rmem_max value by c code

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix

I tried to increase the value `SO_RCVBUF` using

`getsockopt(udp_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &rcvBufferSize, &sockOptSize)`

but I am not able to increase it more than `rmem_max` value .

How can I increase it using [c](/questions/tagged/c) language.

I don't want to increase it by command :

```
$ sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=value
```

Answer (score 2):

As [The Man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) says

> **SO_RCVBUF**
>
> Sets or gets the maximum socket receive buffer in bytes.  The
>                 kernel doubles this value (to allow space for bookkeeping
>                 overhead) when it is set using setsockopt(2), and this doubled
>                 value is returned by getsockopt(2).  The default value is set
>                 by the /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default file, and **the maximum
>                 allowed value is set by the `/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max` file**.
>                 The minimum (doubled) value for this option is 256.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

So with permissions on that file you can directly modify it.

Comment: You can use fopen, fprintf, and fclose.