# How to increase net.core.rmem_max value from c code

Tags: fedora, c

I tried to increase the value SO_RCVBUF by getsockopt(udp_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &rcvBufferSize, &sockOptSize) but I am not able to increase it more than `rmem_max` value.

So please tell me how can I increase it by C Code. I don't want to increase it by command :

```
$ sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=value
```

Comment: What's the problem with [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41158628/how-to-increase-net-core-rmem-max-value-by-c-code/41158780#41158780)???

Answer (score 1):

In Linux kernels 2.6.14 and above we have SO_RCVBUFFORCE which can be used to override the rmem_max limit. However this needs CAP_NET_ADMIN to be set.

Check https://linux.die.net/man/7/socket.

Answer (score 0):

> So please tell me how can I increase it by C Code

If the process has root rights, then let it `printf` the desired number to

```
/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max
```

Comment: the max limits are there for a reason. If you could change it without any privileges it would defeat the purpose of those limits.